# Base case of recursion code to print well formed numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I found a question online: **Given input size print all well formed numbers of that size.**

**Example**: size = 3
Numbers: 123, 234, 125 etc. Condition, say number is abc then a < b < c

I am trying to write a recursive code for this and since I suck at recursion am not able to figure out the base case, or how to come out of the recursion. I had one idea:

1. I start from with lowest well formed number of the given size (just fill array with `for loop`). Say size = 3, I start with `123`. Then I go on till `arr[0] == (10 - size))` cause that is the max value of `arr[0]` for the given size to be a well formed number.

My function would be `printNumbers(int arr[], int size)`

But am not sure if this would work. Need some pointers on the right direction.

```
public void findNumbers(int arr[], int size, int pos)
    {
        if(arr[0] == (10 - size))
            return;
        if(arr[pos] == (10 - size + pos))
        {
            pos--;
            findNumbers(arr,size,pos);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        arr[pos] = arr[pos] + 1;
        findNumbers(arr,size,pos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int size = 3;
        int pos = size-1;
        int arr[] = new int[size];
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i+1;
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        WellFormed obj = new WellFormed();
        obj.findNumbers(arr, size, pos);
    }
```

Comment: Why not try it and see, then post your code here when you get stuck?

Comment: @DNA: I have shown the code I have written. The problem is it does not stop after it reaches `789`. Not able to figure out how to `break` out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WellFormed {

    public static int maxDigit;

    public void findNumbers(int[] digits, int start, int currPos) {
        if (currPos >= digits.length) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
            return;
        }

        int maxDigitInCurrPos = maxDigit - digits.length + currPos + 1;
        for (int i = start; i <= maxDigitInCurrPos; i++) {
            digits[currPos] = i;
            findNumbers(digits, i+1, currPos + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        WellFormed obj = new WellFormed();
        maxDigit = 5;
        int inputSize = 3;
        int[] digits = new int[inputSize];
        obj.findNumbers(digits, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

This works fine:

```
For inputSize = 3 and maxDigit = 5, output is:

[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be Java?  Here is a solution in five lines of Haskell.  What I like about this (and other Haskell code) is that it basically reads like a definition of the problem.

```
wellFormed::Int->[a]->[[a]]
wellFormed _ [] = []
wellFormed 1 xs = map (\x -> [x]) xs
wellFormed n (x:xs) = helper n x xs ++ wellFormed n xs
  where helper n init rest = map ((:) init) (wellFormed (n - 1) rest)

> wellFormed 3 "123456789"
["123","124","125","126","127","128","129","134","135","136","137","138","139","145","146","147","148","149","156","157","158","159","167","168","169","178","179","189","234","235","236","237","238","239","245","246","247","248","249","256","257","258","259","267","268","269","278","279","289","345","346","347","348","349","356","357","358","359","367","368","369","378","379","389","456","457","458","459","467","468","469","478","479","489","567","568","569","578","579","589","678","679","689","789"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more a block than no conception of the problem, seeing your clear description. So for once I answer to such typical "homework".

```
public void giveWellFormedNumbers(int inputSize) {
    int[] digits = new int[intputSize];
    giveWFNumbers(digits, 0, 1);
}

/**
 * @param fromIndex the numbers of digits done, the starting index to continue.
 */
private giveWFNumbers(int[] digits, int fromIndex, int fromDigitValue) {
    if (fromIndex >= digits.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
        return;
    }

    // Do one digit yourself, at digits[fromIndex]:

    int maxDigit = 10 - digits.length; // What is the maximal digit you have to do?
    for (int digitValue = fromDigitValue; digitValue <= maxDigit; ++digitValue) {
        digits[fromIndex = digitValue;
        giveFWNumbers(digits, fromIndex + 1, digitValue + 1);
    }
}
```

Mind, if this is homework you are not finished.